# Apache process exit 255 (WAPP)

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I get a Parent: child process xxx exited with status 255 error when in a simple

```
$sql = "Select 'sometext'";
$rs = $db->fetchAll ( $sql );
```

statement the sometext exceeds cc. 350 characters length.
Below that length it returns fine.

- Its a localhost for development on Windows 7 64-bit.
- I have recently upgraded to XAMPP Version: 5.6.15 (Apache 2.4, PHP
  5.6), didn't have this problem before.
- Database is Postgresql 9.4
- Using Zend Framework

If entered directly to Postgres it returns the result fine.
Nothing useful in the Apache error log.
No error in the php error log (E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT)

I looked in the Windows Event Log and found the following error:

```
Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.17.0, time stamp: 0x561cc534
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.6.15.0, time stamp: 0x56327b2d
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
```

I tried to downgrade to Xamp 5.5.
I tried to use Wampp (because it is a 64bit package).
The problem remained the same.

I suspect it is some sort of PHP or pdo resource problem, but I don't know how to investigate it further.

Comment: The statement's length doesn't matter, but the work it does will.  How long does the query take to run?  How many records does it return?

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A in order to debug your code: http://serverfault.com/questions/153634/php-exit-status-255-what-does-it-mean

Comment: @Mr. Llama - It is literally just a Select 'sometext'; statement. It should return one row with one field containing 'sometext;.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the Zend Framework library to 1.12 (from 1.10) and that solved the problem.